# Implementing custom Akka Streams Source based on ActorPublisher

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I would like to implement custom `Source[ByteSting]` in Akka Stream. This source should just read data from supplied file and within supplied bytes range and propagate it downstream.

At first I thought, that this can be done by implementing Actor which mixes in [ActorPublisher](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/stream/actor/ActorPublisher.html). This implementation is analogous to `akka.stream.impl.io.FilePublisher` which reads the whole file from supplied path instead of just the data from given bytes range:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel
import java.nio.file.{Path, StandardOpenOption}

import akka.actor.{ActorLogging, DeadLetterSuppression, Props}
import akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisher
import akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisherMessage.{Cancel, Request}
import akka.util.ByteString

import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

class FilePublisher(pathToFile: Path, startByte: Long, endByte: Long) extends ActorPublisher[ByteString]
  with ActorLogging{

  import FilePublisher._

  private val chunksToBuffer = 10
  private var bytesLeftToRead = endByte - startByte + 1
  private var fileChannel: FileChannel = _
  private val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8096)

  private var bufferedChunks: Vector[ByteString] = _

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    try {
      log.info("Starting")
      fileChannel = FileChannel.open(pathToFile, StandardOpenOption.READ)
      bufferedChunks = readAhead(Vector.empty, Some(startByte))
      log.info("Chunks {}", bufferedChunks)
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(ex) => onErrorThenStop(ex)
    }
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {

    log.info("Stopping")
    if (fileChannel ne null)
      try fileChannel.close() catch {
        case NonFatal(ex) => log.error(ex, "Error during file channel close")
    }
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Request =>
      readAndSignalNext()
      log.info("Got request")
    case Continue =>
      log.info("Continuing reading")
      readAndSignalNext()
    case Cancel =>
      log.info("Cancel message got")
      context.stop(self)
  }

  private def readAndSignalNext() = {

    log.info("Reading and signaling")
    if (isActive) {
      bufferedChunks = readAhead(signalOnNext(bufferedChunks), None)
      if (isActive && totalDemand > 0) self ! Continue
    }
  }

  @tailrec
  private def signalOnNext(chunks: Vector[ByteString]): Vector[ByteString] = {

    if (chunks.nonEmpty && totalDemand > 0) {
      log.info("Signaling")
      onNext(chunks.head)
      signalOnNext(chunks.tail)
    } else {
      if (chunks.isEmpty && bytesLeftToRead > 0) {
        onCompleteThenStop()
      }
      chunks
    }
  }

  @tailrec
  private def readAhead(currentlyBufferedChunks: Vector[ByteString], startPosition: Option[Long]): Vector[ByteString] = {

    if (currentlyBufferedChunks.size < chunksToBuffer) {

      val bytesRead = readDataFromChannel(startPosition)
      log.info("Bytes read {}", bytesRead)
      bytesRead match {
        case Int.MinValue => Vector.empty
        case -1 =>
          log.info("EOF reached")
          currentlyBufferedChunks // EOF reached
        case _ =>
          buffer.flip()
          val chunk = ByteString(buffer)
          buffer.clear()

          bytesLeftToRead -= bytesRead
          val trimmedChunk = if (bytesLeftToRead >= 0) chunk else chunk.dropRight(bytesLeftToRead.toInt)
          readAhead(currentlyBufferedChunks :+ trimmedChunk, None)
      }

    } else {
      currentlyBufferedChunks
    }
  }

  private def readDataFromChannel(startPosition: Option[Long]): Int = {
    try {
      startPosition match {
        case Some(position) => fileChannel.read(buffer, position)
        case None => fileChannel.read(buffer)
      }
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(ex) =>
        log.error(ex, "Got error reading data from file channel")
        Int.MinValue
    }
  }
}

object FilePublisher {

  private case object Continue extends DeadLetterSuppression

  def props(path: Path, startByte: Long, endByte: Long): Props = Props(classOf[FilePublisher], path, startByte, endByte)
}
```

But turns out that when I materialize `Source` backed by my `FilePublisher` like this:

```
val fileSource = Source.actorPublisher(FilePublisher.props(pathToFile, 0, fileLength))
val future = fileSource.runWith(Sink.seq)
```

nothing happens and the source doesn't propagate data further downstream.

Is there any other correct way to materialize `Source` based on my `FilePublisher` or should I not use this API and just implement custom processing stage like described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-customize.html#Custom_processing_with_GraphStage) ?

The problem with CustomStage approach is that its trivial implementation will perform IO straight away in this stage. I guess, I could move IO from stage to custom thread pool or actor, but this would require some form of synchronization between stage and the actor.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by mistake in pattern matching of `receive` method:
This line `case Request =>` should be instead `case Request(_)` because `Request` is actually case class with single parameter (`final case class Request(n: Long)`)and not case object as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're not currently using a separate dispatcher for IO operations. [Here's](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-io.html#Streaming_File_IO) the docs section explaining why not doing this could lead to nasty blocking in your application.

Akka Streams wraps the `FilePublisher` in a `FileSource` by using a specific, thread-pool based dispatcher. You can check out their code for inspiration [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/io/IOSources.scala#L23).

Comment: Thanks, that's a valid point. I've been planning to add usage of separate dispatcher in future.